# How to configure eclipse for C?

Tags: c, eclipse

I've installed an eclise for C/C++ developers. But unable to compile the code. It doesn't get `#include <stdio.h>` saying: unresolved inclusion `<stdio.h>`. I wonder if I have to make some addtional configuration. My OS is Windows 7 32 bit.
Please advise.

Comment: Did you install a compiler? Eclipse for C/C++ developers does not contain the compilers or libraries, you need to install MinGW or similar for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well if such basic things do not work, then you must have missed to install a proper toolchain. Just downloading Eclipse and CDT will not "do" it.  So install some usable compiler, linker etc.